# True if sigma-compact

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Halo to readers of this post, I would like to enquire from the book of Royden's Real Analysis book, there is a lemma which I believe is wrong but am not certain. Perhaps someone can how me a counter-example?

> Let $X$ a locally compact Hausdorff space and $E$ be a subset of $X$ such that $E \bigcap K$ is a Borel Set for each compact set $K$. Then $E$ is a Borel set.

I think this is only true if $X$ is sigma-compact. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What do we know about the topology of $X$?

Comment: The X is a Locally Compact Hausdorff Space.

Comment: I couldn't find this Lemma from Royden's book. What page is it?

Comment: Found it now. And it's true that this is very questionable since no proof is given. If $X$ is $\sigma$-compact then the Lemma is true, as $E$ is a countable union of Borel sets. Let me see if I'm able to do something with the locally compact Hausdorff case.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I tried making a counterexample but seem not able to do one. Perhaps someone or you might be able to show me one. I anticipate your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with Nate, I'm leaning towards the side that Royden's Lemma is false.

Look at page 5 in the ***Notes on measure and integration in locally compact spaces*** written by William Arveson from Berkeley. The document can be found on his [homepage](http://math.berkeley.edu/~arveson/) by following the link "papers" and scrolling down to the section titled "Lecture notes and snippets". Here is the [direct download link](http://math.berkeley.edu/~arveson/Dvi/rieszMarkov.pdf).

It seems that they refer to Royden's Lemma and say that it is misleading, providing seemingly a counter-example for someone (with more knowledge than me) to verify it if possible.

---

However, a weaker result does hold, which I believe Royden might have assumed to imply the above result since the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is generated by closed sets.

Namely, that if $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space and $F\subset X$ is a set for which $F\cap K$ is closed for all compact $K\subset X$, then $F$ is closed. I believe that it can be shown with the following argument:

Assume the contrary that $F$ is not closed. Then we find $x\in\bar{F}\setminus F$ where $\bar{F}$ denotes the closure of $F$ in $X$. In particular, this means that $U\cap F\neq \emptyset$ for all open neighborhoods $U$ of $x$. Since $X$ is locally compact, we find an open neighborhood $U_{x}$ of $x$ so that $\bar{U_{x}}$ is compact. Thus $V:=\bar{U_{x}}\cap F\neq\emptyset$ and $V$ is closed by our assumption. Since $x\notin F\supset V$ then $x\notin V$, and since $V$ is closed its complement is open. Thus we find an open neighborhood $W$ of $x$ so that $x\in W\subset V^{c}$. We then take $G=U_{x}\cap W$ as an open neighborhood of $x$, whence
\begin{align*}
G=U_{x}\cap W\subset U_{x}\cap V^{c}=U_{x}\cap(\bar{U_{x}}\cap F)^{c}=U_{x}\cap(\bar{U_{x}}^{c}\cup F^{c})=U_{x}\cap F^{c}.
\end{align*}
But this implies that $G\cap F\subset U_{x}\cap F^{c}\cap F=\emptyset$, which is a contradiction since $x\in\bar{F}$ and $G$ is an open neighborhood of $x$. Thus $F$ must be closed.

Comment: I changed your link to the webpage of the author of the note you were referring to, I hope that's fine with you. There is indeed a nice counterexample to be found on page 5. Its construction starts on the line beginning with ***A bad apple*** and relies on the "explicit" transfinite construction of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets on $\omega_1 \times \mathbb R$, where $\omega_1$ is discrete.

Answer (score 2):

I think $\omega_1$ should supply a counterexample.  Compact sets are countable, so every set $E$ has the property that $E \cap K$ is Borel for all compact $K$.  But I'm pretty sure $\omega_1$ contains non-Borel sets (assuming enough choice), though I don't know a proof off the top of my head.